# loop through a Form_for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, foreach, form-for

I have "rails generated scaffold Post" and im trying to convert the posts.each index to form_for so I can use "remote: true" the AJAX.

**Problem**: My code doesn't show my records. It just displays the table thread headings.

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end
```

**^^^ So i have only made these change to the controller and the following code is failing to display the post records**

```
<tbody>
<% @posts.each do |mend| %>
<% form_for(mend) do |f| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= f.text_field :title %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :content %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :verify %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :date %></td>
    <td><%= f.text_field :rate %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post_path(f) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(f) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', @post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to get the code to list all of the records as post content. and I need to use form_for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have got a bit confused somewhere along the way.

You don't need to use form_for to be able to do AJAX requests and you have quite a few bugs anyway in the way you have implemented it.

If I understand your requirements correctly it seems what you are attempting to do is simply display the posts in a table with links to the show, edit, destroy actions for each entry. Those links you want to invoke as AJAX requests.

To get you started:

1. Change the index action to simply:

   `def index
   @posts = Post.all
   end`
2. The tbody declaration should become:

   `<tbody>
      <%= render @posts %>
   </tbody>`
3. Create a `_post.html.erb` partial that will be responsible for rendering each row of the table:

   `<tr>
       <td><%= @post.title %></td>
       <td><%= @post.content %></td>
       <td><%= @post.verify %></td>
       <td><%= @post.date %></td>
       <td><%= @post.rate %></td>
       <td><%= link_to 'Show', post_path(@post), remote: true %></td>
       <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post), remote: true %></td>
       <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', @post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true %></td>
     </tr>`

Comment: but if I want the the entire partial so that I can manipulate it where do a I place "remote: true"

Comment: not sure i follow - i have added the remote: true statements to the link_to helpers

Answer (score 0):

You should render your form_for line, it's not enough just to render fields.

Try using:

```
<%= form_for(mend) do |f| %>
```

instead of:

```
<% form_for(mend) do |f| %>
```